# code giving error subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

Below code is giving me error of subscript out of range.it is giving me error at   this line:

```
[ oSheet.Cells(i,5).Value = g(h) ]
```

I am using above code to seperate string using split function. I have have the following data in excel in one cell:

Pankaj sharma;#234;#khushal verma;#786;#parul datta;#456;#

I would like to convert it to this using VBA:

pankaj sharma

khushal verma

```
Dim c

Dim d

Dim h


Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\test4.xlsm")

objExcel.Visible = True

objExcel.displayalerts = false

Set objExcel2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

strPathExcel = "C:\Users\ssontakke\Desktop\test6.xlsx"

objExcel2.Workbooks.open strPathExcel 

Set oSheet = objExcel2.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

a = 2

i = 2

j = 2


Do Until objExcel.Cells(a, 1).Value = ""

c = 0
d = 0
h = 0
inputText=objExcel.Cells(j, 5).Value
Do Until c = objExcel.Cells(j, 4).Value
g = split(inputText,";#")

oSheet.Cells(i,3).Value = g(h)

c = c + 1
i = i + 1
d = d + 1
h = h + 2

Loop

i = i + 1

a = a + 1

j = j + 1

Loop

objExcel.Save

objExcel2.Save

objExcel.Quit

objExcel2.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

`g` does not have `h` number of elements (or, correctly, `h-1` number elements). `h` is an invalid index for the array.

This is (likely) because the string that is being split (`inputText`) does not contain the expected number of delimiters `;#`, or perhaps the string is empty.

E.g., the string "zero#;one#;two" after split would be:

"zero" at index 0

"one" at index 1

"two" at index 2

If you tried to get `g(3)`, no such element exists - "subscript out of range."

Comment: but it gives me result for some lines and then it shows error for subscript out of range, how to solve this error any way to solve this error

Comment: Debug the code. What is the value of `inputText` and the value of `h` when the code errors?

Comment: actually the input text value necomes 13 and the h value becomes 14

Comment: i mean there is some irregularity in data therefore is there any way to split that data without any loop or something external loop or anything